# Twig/html image dissapear after few sec

Tags: html, symfony, twig, admin-generator

Im trying to put image in a list of objects. At this point, no problem everything is loading fine even my images appears.

Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8S1Y.png

But after 5.02 seconds(always the same) all images crashes.

Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPXFX.png

And when i go to the broken link in the console, the image work perfectly fine And the link dont change bewteen the first and the second picture.

i tried clearing the cache of my browser, clearing the cache of symfony but im kinda lost, i dont get why the link (who dont change at all between the time it work and the time it dont work) crashes...

If anybody here have an idea, ill take it with great pleasure ^^

Thanks.

I get the images :

```
protected function getMediaQuery() {

    $odm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
    $Ad = $odm->getRepository('InstabayAdBundle:Ad')
            ->findAll();
    $AdMediaUri = array("0");

    foreach ($Ad as $test) {
        $AdMedia = $test->getMedia();

        $id = $test->getId();

        if( $AdMedia->first() == ""){
            $file = "";
        } else{
            $file = $AdMedia->first(); 
        }

        array_push($AdMediaUri, $file->getUriName(), $id);
    }

    return $AdMediaUri;
}
```

I render them in the templates :

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->parseRequestForPager();

    $form = $this->getFilterForm();

    $media = $this->getMediaQuery();

    return $this->render('InstabayBackAdminBundle:BackAdList:index.html.twig', $this->getAdditionalRenderParameters() + array(
                'Ads' => $this->getPager(),
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'media' => $media,
                'countMedia' => count($media),
                'sortColumn' => $this->getSortColumn(),
                'sortOrder' => $this->getSortOrder(),
                'scopes' => $this->getScopes(),
    ));
}
```

And finnaly, this is what i do in the templates :

```
  {% set i = 0 %}
  {% for i in 0..countMedia-1  %}
              {% if media[i] == Moderation.referenceId %}
            <img src="{{ media[i-1] }}">
          {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Admingenerator generate line himself based on what he found in the mybundle\document\mybase so using a for is the only way i found by comparing the id of the image and the id of the annonce im in :/ if its the same, i put the image in the line... Dunno if its the best way

And i really dont get why its not working cause it worked 2 days ago and i just added a calendar in the filters form (and i already tried removing it, its not working the image still crashes):/

Comment: Are you using some `JS` library in order to dynamically load images?

Comment: No, Im taking the url from my mongodb database by overwriting the controller of admingenerator and i render in the twig with a {% for %} to put the right picture in the right line. I updated my post with the code i use !

Comment: Did you try running your app in another browser?

Comment: Yes, i just did, its working perfectly fine in firefox and bug in chrome... I find where it come from, i give my content a content-length and the bug go away if i remove it... I got to find out why chrome dont accept the Content-Length

Answer (score 0):

Disable AdBlock Plus (or whatever adblock plugin you have) or whitelist your local server.